# Proof/testing correctness of generic functions

Tags: generics, haskell, quickcheck

(This is not about theorem proving is about testing in practice like `quickCheck`)

Let `f` some generic function

```
f :: RESTRICTIONS => GENERICS
```

with some "desirable" properties (i.e. is not a hack, is immutable, ...) typically a pure Haskell generic function.

Suppose we want test it, the main question is

**if we have (well) tested that function for one specific type (e.g. `Int`), can we assume it is correct for all types?** (matching restrictions, of course)

(with "well tested" I mean "all" function `{domain X properties}` have been tested)

Theorically **we can** be sure but, I'm not sure if some additional property, restriction, ... at instantiation process (i.e. compilation) maybe have influence.

Thanks!

**NOTE** tests maybe use certain type specific properties (e.g. `Int`) but these properties *can not* be part of tested properties. E.g. if `Monoid` is a restriction then, associativity *can* be part of tested properties (but not commutativity if is not a restriction).

**EXAMPLE**

let `f`

```
repeatedHeader :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
repeatedHeader (x:y:_) = x == y
repeatedHeader _ = False

test1 = repeatedHeader [1,1,2] == True
test2 = repeatedHeader [1,2,3] == False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be sure only in the trivial case that RESTRICTIONS is empty or at least does not mention the generic type in question.

In all other cases, your function depends on functionality of type class instances. But even if all **existing** instances behave the way you expect, this does not have to be true for the type class instance that is written tomorrow.

So, it is a question of enforcing certain properties in instances. And this is generally a weak point, because type class laws are mostly stated informally only. For example, Haskell can't and won't prevent you from making a faulty Eq or Ord instance.

A real world example would be a test of a function like:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
```

Now, we know we do have types that overflow silently, like Int. Others don't. This is silently tolerated in the Num class, because, well, life is just like that. Hence, once you did all tests using `Double` you can still get surprised if you use `f` on `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't be sure.

Consider

```
f :: (Fractional a) => a -> a
f x = (2 * x^2 + 2) / (x^2 + 1)
```

You'd now say, evidently `f x ≡ 2`. And sure enough,

> Prelude> map f [-2, -1.6 .. 3]
>   [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0]

In fact, it does provably hold for all `Rational` arguments, as well as for any non-transfinite real type. Yet it's easily broken when you allow more general `Fractional` types:

> Prelude Data.Complex> f (0 :+ 1)
>   NaN :+ NaN

The crucial point is basically that all<sup>1</sup> `Real` types have extra laws, notably `x^2 >= 0`, which don't hold for the general `Num` case.

---

A better example might be

```
g :: Num a => a -> a
g = (+1)
```

Intuitively, `g x > x`, and it holds for all `Integer`s. But that's actually not necessarily true...

> Prelude Data.Modular> map (((x :: ℤ/5) -> g x > x) . fromInteger) [0 .. 10]
>   [True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,False,True]

---

<sup>1</sup>Disconsidering numerical issues with e.g. `Double`.

Comment: Your premise `f x ≡ 2` is not correct (i.e. your first test is not correct). ..."all" function {domain X properties} have been tested...

Comment: @josejuan: I didn't make it explicit what type is used, but, obviously I meant "properly real" types. `Rational` is the only exact one in the standard libraries; that fulfills `f x ≡ 2` for all possible values, as can be proven quite easily.

Comment: you can't (should not) do a generic function for only a non-restricted subset of all possible types (add restrictions if you wish). You can't grant the existence of `1 / (x^2 + 1)` only knowing is `Fractional`, for that reason, conclude that `f x = 2` is not correct. The same applies to `Num`, you need `TotalOrder` restriction to your `g` function if you wish conclude `g x > x` for all `x`. I see difficult to get solid definitions for all class dependencies (as @ingo has written). Thank you anyway!

Comment: @josejuan: I disagree. The complex instantiation of `f` is perfectly reasonable (perhaps not for this contrived constant-thing, but sure enough for functions with actual poles in the complex plane). It does have this ugly undefined spot; we'd wish to count that out through the type system but unfortunately it's not feasible. — You just can't go as deep with proofs in Haskell as in Agda / Idris / Coq, I don't think it's generally necessary either (you can always use those assistants to proove programs written in other languages as well).

Comment: About using `>` on a non-`TotalOrder`, that's a point. I didn't preperly read it from your question that you wanted to count such properties out.